# Копирование изображений из фигмы. Почему изображение не вставляется?

Tags: windows, интерфейс, figma, копирование

Есть макет в фигме. Выделяю изображение в фигме, нажимаю <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, открываю Paint, пытаюсь вставить в него с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, но изображение не вставляется.

Answer (score 0):

Экспортируйте изображение из Фигмы через Export (выделить нужное изображение, нажать справа Export, выбрать формат, экспортировать)и скормите его Paint не через буфер, а как изображение с диска.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XnqR.png